# Getting ID From Firestore document in NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have an `async` page in which I load an array of data from Firestore. I want to extract the Document ID from that and use it.

I know the function to do this which would be:

```
customers.docs.map((doc) => ({
  id: doc.id,
  ...doc.data(),
}));
```

However, when I am trying to loop over the items to create `<div>`'s I get stuck.

My page code is below:

```
async function getCustomers() {
  const customers = await getDocs(collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "client"));
  return customers;
}

export default async function CustomersPage() {
  const customers = await getCustomers();
  const customerData = [];

  customers.forEach((customer) => {
    customerData.push(customer.data());
  });

<div>
  {customerData.map((customer) => {
    return (
      // SOME ELEMENTS USING CUSTOMER
    )
  })}
</div>
```

The only way I have managed to loop through the items is to use a separate array. Which of course doesn't allow me access to the document ID. What can I try next?

Comment: Since data is loaded from Firestore asynchronous, you'll want to store the data in the state of your component - which then triggers the UI to be rerendered. I recommend reading up on [using `useState` and `useEffect` with Firestore](https://www.google.com/search?q=google-cloud-firestore+reactjs+usestate+useeffect).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this is a server side component so using state is not an option.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.